# Draw a box around canvas getImageData

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm currently working with some images in canvas, and I would like to draw a box around an image with a transparent background (see the example at the bottom)

I'm getting my data through: `context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

I already got only the black (not transparent) data inside my result; with this I tried the [marching squares algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) suggested by a few stack-overflowers, but I couldn't quite figure that out.

I also tried cycling through all the data and get the `minX`, `minY`, `maxX`, `maxY`, so I can draw a box with these 4 points, but I didn't know how to them.
Any suggestions on this?

---

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkxlW.png]

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: I suggest that you create a code sample in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of what your tried to help us help you.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Finding the bounding box for the shape to enclose? Creating a box with a transparent centre? Making the border line semi-transparent? Is it really a marching-ants feature you want?

Comment: Yes, sorry, here's a JSfiddle with my code (I'm making motion detection with JS) https://jsfiddle.net/hvsze4dL/. The jsfiddle wont work (can't bind to window) if you copy the code to a local file it works.

Usage:
var test = new Watcher('body', {});
test.startCapture();
test.takeSnapshot();
test.watch();

WARNING: uses your webcam

Comment: **TO ALL VIEWERS OF THIS QUESTION!** In a previous post of mine I mistakenly called the "marching **squares** boundary finding algorithm" the "marching ants algorithm".  The questioner intends to refer to the "marching squares" algorithm which finds the boundary path outlining a common group of pixels. Very sorry to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Logic steps

To scan for the bounding box of a shape you could do the following steps. Assuming you have extracted the bitmap (`ImageData`) from canvas, `x` and `y` are used to iterate over the bitmap:

1. Scan from top to bottom, line by line. At first solid pixel found, store current `y` position as `y1`, skip to next step
2. Scan from bottom to `y1`, line by line. At first solid pixel found, store current `y` position as `y2`
3. Scan horizontally from left to right within `y1` to `y2`. Initialize `x1` with *width* of canvas. When a solid pixel is found on current line *and* `x` has *lower* value than current `x1`, set `x1` = current `x` and skip to next line
4. Scan horizontally from right to `x1`. Initialize `x2` with *0*. When a solid pixel is found on current line *and* `x` has *higher* value than current `x2`, set `x2` = current `x` and skip to next line
5. Size of area would of course be: `width = x2 - x1`, `height = y2 - y1`.

Anti-aliased shaped can affect the size. You can include checking alpha channel for solid to reduce this influence.

The scanning can be optimized for left and right edges by updating the loop to use the new x1/x2 value as limits. Use `Uint32Array` to check for pixel values.

## Proof-of-concept

A non-optimized implementation showing the result of the above steps. It will check any non-alpha values. You can for example replace 0xff000000 with 0x80000000 to check alpha values > 127 if you want to reduce influence of the anti-aliasing. If you don't have alpha just check for the actual color value (note that some images are color corrected so a tolerance can be wise to consider).

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    btn = document.querySelector("button"),
    w = ctx.canvas.width,
    h = ctx.canvas.height,
    img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = ""; img.onload = plot; img.src = "//i.imgur.com/lfsyAEc.png";

btn.onclick = plot;

function plot() {
  var iw = img.width, ih = img.height,
      x = Math.random() * (w - iw * 0.5), y = Math.random() * (h - ih * 0.5),
      s = (Math.random() * 30 - 15)|0;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(Math.random() * Math.PI - Math.PI * 0.5);
  ctx.drawImage(img, -(iw + s) * 0.5, -(ih + s) * 0.5, iw + s, ih + s);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  analyze();
}

function analyze() {
  var data = new Uint32Array(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h).data.buffer),
      len = data.length,
      x, y, y1, y2, x1 = w, x2 = 0;
  
  // y1
  for(y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      if (data[y * w + x] & 0xff000000) {
        y1 = y;
        y = h;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  //todo y1 and the others can be undefined if no pixel is found.
  
  // y2
  for(y = h - 1; y > y1; y--) {
    for(x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      if (data[y * w + x] & 0xff000000) {
        y2 = y;
        y = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // x1
  for(y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      if (x < x1 && data[y * w + x] & 0xff000000) {
        x1 = x;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // x2
  for(y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
    for(x = w - 1; x > x1; x--) {
      if (x > x2 && data[y * w + x] & 0xff000000) {
        x2 = x;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // mark area:
  ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + (360 * Math.random()) + ", 80%, 50%)";
  ctx.strokeRect(x1 + 0.5, y1 + 0.5, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
}
```

```css
body {background:#aaa;margin:1px 0}
canvas {border:1px solid #777; background:#f0f0f2}
```

```html
<button>Again</button><br>
<canvas width=640 height=165></canvas>
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for your reply, I'll try it out.

Comment: I think you mean ``Uint8ClampedArray``

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no, I meant Uint32Array (`var data = new Uint32Array(imagedata.data.buffer`). This will speed up iteration.

Comment: @K3N Or just check ``N % 4 === 3`` pixel, since he's checking alpha transparency. You can have colored pixels in an image that are fully transparent, and converting the buffer to a ``Uint32Array`` would yield non-zero values for colored + fully transparent pixels.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `if (pixel & 0xff00000) { ...}; // has alpha`  is still faster than modulo and Uint8*.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to use modulo... ``for (var i = 3; i < imagedata.data.length; i += 3) { var pixel = imagedata.data[i]; }`` is just as fast to iterate.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts see http://jsperf.com/uint32-vs-uint8-iteration-canvas (not sure why FF result isn't accumulated, but the diff was even larger in FF, only IE was reverse)

Comment: @K3n see http://jsperf.com/uint32-vs-uint8-iteration-canvas/2 Note that constructing the ``Uint32Array`` is in fact part of the performance evaluation, and while it has ~20% boost in performance on Chrome and Opera, on Firefox and Safari, it is drastically worse.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts in that case, so is retrieving the data itself :) http://jsperf.com/uint32-vs-uint8-iteration-canvas/3 (and delete has nothing to do in there, it's to delete properties on an object, not arrays). In any case, I was pointing to *iteration*. You usually work with more than one iteration on the same buffer (which you get once, like here). As you will scan several lines several times I am convinced that using 32-bits is faster in total (which is all that matters really in the end).

Comment: @K3N I ran the tests on the last perf and aside from Safari which is admittedly crap, the performances are about equal when including the data retrieval and construction of the array. If you're only concerned with iteration, it seems to offer a consistent 20% boost across browsers, so I concur. I am curious as to why this is the case though.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it's complex - instructions dealing w wider registers at CPU level is generally faster than smaller ones as more data is handled per operation, but influenced by cache, cache-lines, piping, parallelism etc. (I have more 68k assembler background than x86 so my terms can be a bit off, and admittedly is a bit rusty since it's been 15 years since I touched assembler). And of course, how the browser engine optimizes to byte-code is a key. FF does well nowadays (not sure why it spend so much time creating a 32-bit view as it points to the same byte-buffer..), but all has its quirks.