# How can I determine the size of the content in an HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas, which is initially sized to (for example) 320 x 200.

Various circles, lines and text are added to the canvas via a process over which I have no control or visibility of.

After these things are added, I sometimes end up with a lot of white space because (for example) only one line and one circle was added and the total width and height of those items is 100 x 50.

I have no way to pre-compute the width and height of the content that will be added.

Is there a way to look at the canvas to determine the boundaries of the content? A simple methodology that would work in my scenario would be to find the first and last row and column that has non-white pixels.

Once it has been determined, I believe I can then resize or redraw the canvas with the appropriate height and width.

Comment: You mean something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30511645/1693593)?

Comment: That looks promising! I will see what I can do with it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following function is used to clip a canvas (usually of transparent pixels)

If you don't want to clip then uncomment the bounds return and remove lines after that and you get the top,left width and height of rectangle not containing the pixel value `ignoreABGR`  for white `ignoreABGR = 0xFFFFFFFF` for black `ignoreABGR = 0xFF000000` for transparent `ignoreABGR = 0`

```
function clipCanvas(ctx, ignoreABGR){
    var x, y, i, left, right, top, bottom, imgDat;
    const w = ctx.canvas.width;
    const h = ctx.canvas.height;
    const data = new Uint32Array((imgDat = ctxS.getImageData(0,0,w,h)).data.buffer);
    left = w
    i = right = 0;
    for(y = 0; y < h; y+=1){
        for(x = 0; x < w; x+=1){
            if(data[i++] !== ignoreABGR){
                top = top === undefined ? y : top;
                bottom = y;
                left = x < left ? x : left;
                right = x > right ? x : right;
            }
        }
    }
    // add bounds return 
    // return {left,top,width : (right - left) + 1, height :(bottom - top) + 1};
    ctx.canvas.width = (right - left) + 1;
    ctx.canvas.height  = (bottom - top) + 1;
    ctx.putImageData(imgDat, -left, -top);
    return ctx;
}
```